# How could to close and open navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, navbar

I try to use this navbar, but it doesn't close and open, what script should I add.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md"> 
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="/logo.png" alt="image" height="30">
  </a> 
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav3">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.firan.ir">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Style:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
.navbar-toggler {
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

Comment: What kind of behavior exactly are you looking for? To open/close or expand/collapse? Also, next time try to be specific about the version of the library that you are using. In this case, Bootstrap 4.

Comment: As to your question, from what I see it seems that your forgot to add the target on which you want the click event to act, i.e., to define the `data-target` in the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, your forgot to add the target on which you want the click event to act. Since, in this case, you want `data-target` to trigger everything wrapped around `#navbarNav3` to expand/collapse, you just add `data-target="#navbarNav3"` to the button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light"> 
  
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="/logo.png" alt="image" height="30">
  </a> 
  
  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" data-target="#navbarNav3">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav3">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://www.firan.ir">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>

</body>
```